# Jelastic - using private repository in JPS

Tags: jelastic

Is there a way to use private docker repository images when launching a new environment using jps?

From marketplace, i can add docker containers from private repository and launch them, no problem there. But even when the image has been added to the marketplace, the new environment launched using jps, cannot find the image... "adding privateRepo/image:latest node to env-xxxx | Image not found. Please double-check your entries"

[edit]

Below is a simple example JPS to start from... The karppo/testing image is in hub.docker.com as a private repository and I would like to launch it using JPS.

```
{
"jpsType": "install",
"description": {
    "text": "repo testing qwe",
    "short": "repo testing qwe"
},
"name": "repo testing",
"success": {
    "text": "repo testing ok"
},
"nodes": [
    {
        "image": "karppo/testing",
        "count": 1,
        "cloudlets": 2,
        "nodeGroup": "purkka",
        "displayName" : "purkka"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: it's pretty easy and for sure possible. We tested - works fine. Can you install this docker using a usual way https://docs.jelastic.com/docker-custom-registry? If yes, there can be a mistake in your JPS. Can we take a look?

Comment: I can install the docker the usual way, no problem in there. Just cannot figure out, how i can do it from JPS. Added example JPS to original post, what uses hub.docker.com private repository image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a bit of help with this. The thing that i was looking for is "registry".

```
{
"jpsType": "install",
"description": {
    "text": "repo testing qwe",
    "short": "repo testing qwe"
},
"name": "repo testing",
"success": {
    "text": "repo testing ok"
},
"nodes": [
    {
        "image": "karppo/testing",
        "registry": {
            "user": "username",
            "password": "*******************",
            "url": "registry-1.docker.io"
        },
        "count": 1,
        "cloudlets": 2,
        "nodeGroup": "purkka",
        "displayName" : "purkka"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Absolutely right. Just writing an answer for you :)

Comment: In your case, you can skip url, since docker hub is a default one. Also, you can specify a particular tag in image, if needed. For example -
 karppo/testing:latest