# Jelastic - changing private repository credentials

Tags: jelastic

Relates to Jelastic environment launched using JPS with docker private repository credentials. [Jelastic - using private repository in JPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273639/jelastic-using-private-repository-in-jps)

How can i change the repository credentials to previously launched environment? I have tried to add the new changed credentials to "Marketpace / Docker containers / Custom", but it seems that the credentials won't be updated to previously made environments. When trying to redeply old environment, i get Warning message "The authorization has failed while trying to fetch image data from the registry... ". With new environments, launched after the password change, there is no issue.

Comment: It seems that the version of the current Jelastic environment that we are using is 5.3.x, and the ability to change the repository credentials comes in version 5.4. https://docs.jelastic.com/release-notes-54 "Private Docker Container Credentials Change"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is absent on platform versions below 5.3.2 build 10. It was added in the 10th build in frames of the JE-30173 (Credentials to a private Docker registry can not be adjusted). You can check it at the release notes: https://docs.jelastic.com/release-notes-53.
If you need to change credentials in the current version, please, contact your hoster.